# Программа зависает при скачивании файлов с помощью Webclient C#

Tags: c#, webclient

Есть код:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
var mannyScreen = HD.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@rel='group']");
if (mannyScreen != null)
            {
                string screen = "";
                int numberScreen = 0;
                foreach (var node in mannyScreen)
                {  
                    numberScreen = numberScreen + 1;
                    screen = node.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
                    try
                    {    
                        wc.DownloadFile(new Uri("https://manytorrents.pro" + screen), disk.Text + System.IO.Path.GetFileName("screen" + numberScreen + ".jpg"));

                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при попытке скачать " + numberScreen + " скриншот");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Он получает прямые ссылки на картинки, которые затем скачиваются.
Если использовать эту программу там, где быстрый интернет, то зависаний не происходит - поток разблокируется после того, как все найденные картинки скачаются. Но если запустить скачивание там, где инет плохой, иногда программа просто не возвращается из "не отвечает". Особенно это часто происходит, если в процессе скачивания попытаться развернуть приложение. Один-два файла скачаются, а оставшиеся нет.
Пытался обернуть код скачивания в using, но тогда выкидывало ошибку с исключением Webclient.
В блоке try писал так:

```
using (Webclient wbc = new Webclient())
{
     wbc.DownloadFile(new Uri("https://manytorrents.pro" + screen), disk.Text + System.IO.Path.GetFileName("screen" + numberScreen + ".jpg"));
}
```

Подскажите, что можно исправить, чтобы учесть этот недочет со скоростью интернета?

Comment: качайте ваши файлы асинхронно или в параллельном потоке (лучше асинхронно)

Comment: @tym32167 недостаточно ведь заменить DownloadFile на DownloadFileAsync?

Comment: Нет, не достаточно. Если вы хотите дождаться окончания асинхронной операции асинхронно, то нужен await, который можно использовать только в асинхронной функции